# Sagemaker pytorch endpoint error with input data

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to send a payload to a sagemaker endpoint created as follows:

```
model = PyTorchModel(
    name="d2-sku110k-model",
    model_data=training_job_artifact,
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sm_session,
    entry_point="predict_sku110k.py",
    source_dir="container_serving",
    image_uri=serve_image_uri,
    framework_version="1.6.0",
    code_location=f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix_code}",

predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')
```

I have been trying different forms of payloads as a test, for example:

```
import json
payload = json.dumps({"data": [[1,2,3]]})
```

or

```
payload = json.dumps({"data": [[1,2,3]]}).encode('utf8')
```

that I then try to send to the endpoint with:

```
predictor.predict(payload, initial_args={'ContentType': 'application/json'})
```

but I get the error:

> An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary with message "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py", line 124, in transform
> input_data = input_data.decode("utf-8")

where [this](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_inference/transformer.py) is the file referred to in the error message.

Any idea of how the payload should be formatted for this?
(note that the [[1,2,3]] is just as an example, the actual payload will be an image)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the serializer and deserializer for the predictor , for example https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/serializers.html#sagemaker.serializers.JSONSerializer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.